# How to map dynamic response in RestKit?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, restkit

I have two different responses to an object from my service:

**This is the first response when there is no error:**

`{"responseError":{"ApplicationErrorCode":101,"DeveloperMessage":"Code is needed","UserMessage":null},"shortToken":null}`

**This is the second response when there is an error:**

`{"responseError":null,"shortToken":sometoken}`

I've created an object called `RKShortToken` and it looks like this:

```
@interface RKShortToken : NSObject
@property (copy, nonatomic) RKResponseError *responseError;
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *shortToken;
@end
```

Also I have this object called `RKResponseError`:

```
@interface RKResponseError : NSObject
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *applicationErrorCode;
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *developerMessage;
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSString *userMessage;
@end
```

First of all initialize the RestKit client:

```
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:kServiceDevBaseURL];
self.manager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:baseURL];
[self.manager setRequestSerializationMIMEType:RKMIMETypeJSON];
[self.manager setAcceptHeaderWithMIMEType:RKMIMETypeJSON];
[self.manager addResponseDescriptorsFromArray:[RKObjectManager sharedManager].responseDescriptors];
[self.manager addRequestDescriptorsFromArray:[RKObjectManager sharedManager].requestDescriptors];
[self.manager.HTTPClient.operationQueue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:5];
[RKObjectManager setSharedManager:self.manager];
```

Than added a route:

```
RKRoute *shortTokenRoute = [RKRoute routeWithClass:[RKShortToken class] pathPattern:@"users/login/quick/shortToken" method:RKRequestMethodGET];
shortTokenRoute.shouldEscapePath = YES;
[self.manager.router.routeSet addRoute:shortTokenRoute];
```

And than added a descriptor:

```
RKObjectMapping *shortTokenMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[RKShortToken class]];
[shortTokenMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{ @"responseError" : @"responseError", @"shortToken" : @"shortToken" }];
RKResponseDescriptor *shortTokenDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:shortTokenMapping
                                                                                          method:RKRequestMethodAny
                                                                                     pathPattern:@"users/login/quick/shortToken"
                                                                                         keyPath:nil
                                                                                     statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] addResponseDescriptor:shortTokenDescriptor];
```

How do I handle this kind of response with RestKit? I think that something with my Route or Descriptor is wrong..

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are your examples the wrong way round? How is this dynamic? What have you tried?

Comment: @Wain I've edited my question. Check it out please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RKRoute` objects are used for requests so they play no part in processing the response data.

Your response descriptor has an individual mapping: `@"responseError" : @"responseError"` - this would be used if you were mapping the response direct into a dictionary: `@property (copy, nonatomic) NSDictionary *responseError;`.

As you want to map the response into an `RKResponseError` instance you need to create another mapping for that class and use `addRelationshipMappingWithSourceKeyPath:@"responseError" mapping:responseErrorMapping` to connect the new mapping to the 'outer' mapping.

Finally, note that `RK` is the naming prefix for RestKit and you should use a different prefix for classes that you create yourself.